# Loop over n object and return the longest string

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I'm trying to write a function that takes an object whose values are strings and returns the longest string.  Since I'm new to JS, I'm a bit stuck on what I'm missing. Thanks for the help!

I feel like the .length is part of the problem, but I'm not sure how to get the length.  Here is my code:

```
var myObj = {first: 'am', second: 'abc', third: 'greg', fourth: 'helpme', fifth: 'phillllll'};

var myFunc = function (object) {
    var longestString = object[key];
    for (var key in object) {
      if (object[key].length > longestString.length) {
        longestString = object[key];
      }
    }; 
    return longestString;
}
```

Comment: The `=` assignment operator does not mean, "this variable should **always** be such-and-such"; it means, "make this variable equal to the value of such-and-such *as it is right now*."

Comment: Also keep the browser console open when you're working on new code. You need to be aware of errors that are occurring, and that's the only good way to see them.

Comment: The semicolon goes on the last bracket.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had this problem working when I looped over an array of similar data. Now I am just trying to make it work for an object, so im not sure the = part has to do with it being wrong.

Comment: Initialize it with an empty string.

Comment: @cookiemonster Haha, that's what I was thinking when I posted my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.length` is not the problem, you actually used it correctly.  Also, you aren't missing anything, you just got confused with logic, because there *are* problems in your code...

so I fixed it a bit (try this instead):

```
var myObj = {first: 'am', second: 'abc', third: 'greg', fourth: 'helpme', fifth: 'phillllll'};

function myFunc (object) {
    var longestString = '';
    for (var key in object) {
      if (object[key].length > longestString.length) {
        longestString = object[key];
      }
    }
    return longestString;
}

alert(myFunc(myObj));
console.log(myFunc(myObj));
```

**Why does this work?**
It works because initializing `longestString` as an empty [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is a good way to create a string that will be changed later, which is what I changed the variable's definition to because the variable `keys` is [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) until you get to the [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), and you need both variables defined at once, so technically `longestString` was `null`.

(BTW, I made it so it will log the function's output in the console and alert the output.)

Your code had a lot of syntax errors, and as a new user I recognize you probably aren't all-knowing in Javascript, but there *is* something called a console in most browsers, and online and in most IDEs, that you can use (like [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com)).

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AttKz/) that you can take a look at that uses this new code.

Comment: Thanks! Question, why does the `var longestString= '';` work instead of what I wrote? I read over your code vs mine n it seems like that is the main difference

Comment: @jstone It's because the variable key isn't defined until you get to your `for` loop, and you were trying to access it before (added to post).

Comment: when I wrote this using an array instead of an object it worked as `var longestString = array[0];` do you mind telling me why this is different for an object?

Comment: It's because `key` was never defined, so if you had put `object[0]` it would've worked as expected.